# Ajuda para obter valor decimal de máscara input (ionic 3 + br masker)

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Estou com uma dificuldade em um problema que eu acredito ser muito fácil de resolver, porém estou penando bastante para chegar a tal solução.
Eu tenho um simples input que formato utilizando a biblioteca brmasker (ionic3). O usuário digita um valor e ele é formatado em tempo real, até ai tudo bem. No meu console.log recebo o valor formato devidamente em formato string. Porém na hora de subir para o banco de dados este valor, eu preciso que ele seja NÚMERO, então eu uso um parseFloat() como sempre fiz, mas não consigo obter os valores de forma correta, ele não considera as duas casas decimais depois da vírgula e se eu tentar usar um parseFloat(2) ele me retorna uma string, e não um número.

Segue o meu código e alguns prints explicando o problema.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="valorMeta"
  [brmasker]="{money: true, thousand: '.',  decimalCaracter: ',', decimal: '2'}">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

No ts é algo simples como:

```
console.log(this.valorMeta);
console.log(parseFloat(this.valorMeta));
```

As imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui chegar a um resultado um pouco melhor, utilizando essa condição:

console.log(parseFloat(this.valorMeta.replace(',', '.')));

Porém ainda não retorna como esperado, quando os números são muito altos, continua não captuando corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa tratar sua `string`. Retire os pontos e substitua a vírgula por ponto.

```js
const n = '2.368,67',
nG = '256.695.693,25';

console.log(n.split('.').join('').replace(',','.'));

console.log(nG.split('.').join('').replace(',','.'));
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, resolveu dessa forma.